# Whatsapp Sender with Twilio Studio Flow not responding

Tags: twilio, whatsapp

I have created a WhatsApp sender. The sender status is online.
I have wired the sender up to a studio flow. Although, I noticed that there arent any messaging service options and this might be relevant.

[image]

The studio flow is mega simple and looks like this:

[image]

It is published.

In whatsapp, on my phone I send a message to the number associated with the twilio sender.

The message is marked as recieved but not read and I do not get a response of "hello Daaave"!

Any suggestions on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer was provided here https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio/tutorials/customer-support-menu#connect-your-whatsapp-sender-to-your-studio-flow

In short you copy the flows webhook url and set the Twilio Senders incoming message handler to call this!